# Why is the external lens for my smartphone blurry when not at full zoom?

Tags: lens, zoom, manual-focus, smartphone

I've just bought an optical zoom lens for my Samsung S4 (I'm a web developer and blogger so I thought that it would be a handy tool for taking photo's when out and about without my main camera). The thing really is a nice little tool but the problem the whole image is blurry when it's at anything but full 12X zoom. Can anyone tell me why this might be and if there are any solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a zoom lens, but rather a 12x magnifier with a manual focus.  You are not adjusting the amount of zoom, but rather the focus.  It is only not blurry at one setting because that is when the focus is properly adjusted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - The lens that I'm using is this one, http://www.xcsource.com/p_detail.php?id=1228

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me AJ, I misread the description as there are some phone lenses that are labeled as being 4-12x zoom and I thought this was the same. I've just done some testing with it and to be honest it seems like a really great product so I'll probably keep it for now and then see about getting a 4-12x zoom in the near future - Thanks again

Comment: It's very misleading that they repeatedly describe it as a zoom lens.

Comment: @dav1dsm1th - yeah, the details I found on Amazon much more accurately describe it as a 12x magnifier, which is the accurate description of what it is.  Granted, that's also why it can be so cheap and still have reasonable quality.